# Struts 2.0 get some constant value

Tags: jsp, struts

in struts 2.0, view can get action value, but how the view get some value from other class

```
public class sharedvalue
{
   public static string global_set = "hello";
}
```

how view can get this global_Set value, this sharedvalue class is outside the action

Answer (score 0):

As per [the docs](http://struts.apache.org/development/2.x/docs/ognl-basics.html#OGNLBasics-Accessingstaticproperties):

```
<s:property value="@sharedvalue@global_set" />
```

You must set `struts.ognl.allowStaticMethodAccess=true` to enable this–in S2.0 it might be enabled by default, a potential security hole. I'd also recommend not using such an old version of S2.